# While running jmeter for master slave configuration in Non GUI mode, created empty output file

Tags: jmeter, performance

1. Added same execution script on master and slave
2. Change the property file of master by adding slave IP address and uncommenting 
   uncomment this on property file: server.rmi.create=false
3. Run server file on slave command prompt
   : jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname="SlaveIP"
4. Run on Master command prompt
   : jmeter -n -t F:\jmeter3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\Hubdataposting_Test.jmx -l 
     F:\jmeter3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\output.jtl -R "slaveIP" -
     Djava.rmi.server.hostname="MasterIP"
5. Communication get established, output file get created but it create as empty file.

When tried running individually on both servers like master and slave, it works as expected and creates output file as a result.
but when tried with master-slave execution it gives an empty output file

Comment: 2018-02-22 15:34:11,037 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not read file header line for file C:\jmeter3.3\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\test.csv

Comment: @Dmitri T,  what are you trying to tell in the last comment about parameterization ?? Can you please explain me more details? because I have copied test.csv in a slave's respective path

Comment: Is anyone know the solution? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

As per [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) user manual section

> If the test uses any data files, **note that these are not sent across by the client so make sure that these are available in the appropriate directory on each server**.

So you need to copy your `test.csv` file over to all remote slaves.

If for some reason you cannot do it (i.e. slaves are being created from scratch) you can reconsider parameterization to use some `.properties` file which will be passed via [`-G command-line argument`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options).

---

Also be aware that according to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) it is recommended to use the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) (or higher) on next available opportunity.